# Get URL thumbnail like facebook posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using Koala to get user posts From Facebook. I have a JSON object in which I have all posts data for a certain user. In my view I need to display each of these posts. My question here is how to get a thumbnail photo from a shared URL to be inserted in the post, like what Facebook posts look. I can grab the URL by `post['link']` but how to get/parse a thumbnail for it inside this view.

Here is a snippet from my view code:

```
<div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
<% if @posts %>
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, :id => "post", :class => "float-left" do %>
        <h1 id="name"><%= post['from']['name'] %></h1>
        <% if post['type'] == 'status' %>
            <p><%= post['message'] %></p>
        <% end %>
        <% if post['type' == 'link']
    <% end %>
    <br>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And here is what I want to achieve:

[image: Image of URL]

Comment: i don't use koala gem but i know how get some size picture `friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends?fields=id,name,picture.type(large)")` post debug views like `<%= debug variable_name %>`

Comment: Are you trying to make it look like the real FB posts? You'll have to have code to handle the different types of posts (video/image/link) etc. Perhaps you could simplify things by using the Facebook Embedded posts? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?